# jTextField.setText() not working when empty string

Tags: java, netbeans

So, in a giving point of my program I want to clear some text fields on the screen so when the event happens I put `textfield.setText("")` but it didn't worked. I also tryied `textfield.setText(null)`
The .setText() method is working if I put some char inside the string "" but not when it's empty so I cannot erase its content.

What am I missing?

Code snippet: http://pastebin.com/bwpRgRUq

```
private void RbConsActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        BtReg.setVisible(false);

        TFAtividade.setText("-");
        TFAtividade.setEditable(false);

        TFCPF.setText("-");
        TFCPF.setEditable(false);

        TFCargo.setText("-");
        TFCargo.setEditable(false);

        TFEmail.setText("-");
        TFEmail.setEditable(false);

        TFNome.setText("-");
        TFNome.setEditable(false);

        TFSalario.setText("-");
        TFSalario.setEditable(false);

        TFSetor.setText("-");
        TFSetor.setEditable(false);

        RBTemConta.setEnabled(false);

        LBCN.setVisible(true);
        LBCC.setVisible(true);
        TFConsNome.setVisible(true);
        TFConsCPF.setVisible(true);
        this.repaint();

    }
```

**Edit:**
I noticed that when the setText() method was setting an empty "" or null string it is never being called. Now, when I call it giving any string with at least one character, it is being called but only on the second time I click the JRadioButton which triggers those calls. I know that the trigger is working because the components I set to be visible is appearing on the first time I click the JRB.

Comment: please post your code.

Comment: dunno if gonna help much:
http://pastebin.com/TPGMHLps

Comment: Should work. is the method being called?

Comment: What JDK version are you using?

Comment: My JDK version: 1.8.0_66

@Jclassic: yes, the method is being called.

Comment: try putting some value into the textfield immediately before clearing it.

Comment: Didn't worked. It didn't even changed to the immediately before text. And the method is being called

Comment: Post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) with your question (not on pastebin) that demonstrates the problem. Chances are while creating the `SSCCE` you will find the problem. So to create the SSCCE all you need is a frame with a text field and a button. Then you add an ActionListener to the button to clear the text field.

Answer (score 0):

What i do is when i define the JTextField, i do this:

```
JTextField textfield = new JTextField(null);
```

and it create a text field empty!

Comment: Can't do that. I noticed that after I invoke those setText, they are actually set but now shown. So when I click on the textfield it updates like if it was missing some "refresh" function.

Comment: @Welten Schann Ok, so then you can use the method revalidate(), you call it to refresh the GUI. protected void refreshGUI() { this.revalidate(); }